# Adding a hotkey to a button

Tags: hotkeys

I have a GUI in ahk where i have two edit boxes and some buttons.  I have a label attached to the first button which takes the string from first edit box and enters it into the second after modifying it.  This works fine when I click the button, but unfortunately when I use a hotkey for that button, it does not work as intended.  it skips the codes related to the GUI controls.  Can anybody help with this please?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just wanted to assign a hotkey or shortcut key to a button, but when that hotkey is pressed, the label attached to the button does not execute its contents, but when clicked on the same button using mouse, it works fine.

Comment: which means, i am struggling to assign shortcut keys to buttons

Comment: I am creating an application in autohotkey